# How to continue with next command if the remote switch is not responding in an expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I'm passing the switch name from a `bash` script. The `bash` script iterates through a text file and sends the switch name. Sometimes if the switch is not responding, the `expect` script gets stuck. I want the script to wait for some time and move to next switch or at least come out. I have used the timeout but with no help.

```
set timeout 60
.
.
.
expect "*> "
send "ssh -l admin $switchName.XXX.XXXXXX.net switchshow -portname > $filename1\r"
sleep 2
expect {
        "*(yes/no)? " {
                send "yes\r"
                exp_continue
        }

        "*assword: " {
                send "$password\r"
        }
        default {
                exp_continue
        }
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you want to expect to see the "timeout" keyword:

```
expect {
        timeout {
                puts "timed out waiting for $switchName"
        }
        "*(yes/no)? " {
                send "yes\r"
                exp_continue
        }

        "*assword: " {
                send "$password\r"
                exp_continue
        }
        eof
}
```

I also updated your conditions a bit so that you remain in the expect "loop" until the ssh command completes.